# How to remove a class when another element is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple gallery. When the image is clicked it is resized. However, when I click another image, the first one is still active. How to remove the class when I click another image?

```
const imgList = document.querySelectorAll("img");
console.log(imgList);
for (let i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
  imgList[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    imgList[i].classList.toggle("bigger");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without complicating it you can just reset remove `bigger` from all images and set it to the clicked image

```
const imgList = document.querySelectorAll("img");

for (let i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
  imgList[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

    imgList.forEach(el=> el.classList.remove("bigger"))

    imgList[i].classList.add("bigger");
  });
}
```

Comment: `el=> el.classList`. You had `e.classList`

Comment: @symlink thanks I updated it

Comment: If you're going to give a complete solution with `forEach`, you might as well update the outer `for` loop to use `forEach` as well :) It's much cleaner.

Comment: I can do it, but I'll leave it to him, he has `for loop` and `forEach` in his kit now

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to something like this. One way would be simply find the previously selected item and remove the class when a new one is clicked:

```
    const currentlySelectedElem = document.querySelector("img.bigger");
    if (currentlySelectedElem) {
        currentlySelectedElem.classList.remove("bigger");
    }
```

In context, this might look something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(imgElem => {
  imgElem.addEventListener("click", function () {

    // Deselect the last selected image by selecting it and removing the class if needed
    const currentlySelectedElem = document.querySelector("img.bigger");
    if (currentlySelectedElem) {
        currentlySelectedElem.classList.remove("bigger");
    }
    
    // Indicate the current selection
    imgElem.classList.add("bigger");
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

img.bigger {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" />
<img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" />
<img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" />
<img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" />
<img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" />
```

Comment: You could also keep track of the last selected item in a javascript variable, and then remove the class from it that way.

Comment: Where should I put your condition? Because it doesn't work inside the click event or after.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the context, with a few other small improvements to your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yona.